# setup mfc project

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

A word or two about project I have to make.
I have a list of products (XML formatted), and I have to make a bar code of that list.

Here are the requirements:

- Technology has to be MFC, VS 2005 or VS2008
- All functionality must be in one dll
- Same solution should have a simple tester for the dll

I will use pdf417. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf417lib/
Also, I would like to provide an interface, so that different bar codes can be implemented in future.

For example, my dll has "Write" method which is implemented in a separate file for pdf417 and in a separate file for some other bar code, so that user can choose which bar code to use.

Since I have no knowledge of mfc, I really don't know how to even start. I read some tutorials, created the dll with some dummy method, and then tried to use it in tester application, but no luck.

I know that this is a "needle in a haystack" type of a question, but if someone could help me how to setup/architect this project I would be very grateful.

Thanks,
Marko

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you benefit from using MFC if your DLL's client is not an MFC app. You are better off using a standard C interface in your exported functions if you want to support non-MFC clients. Just create a Win32 project and choose the project type as DLL, then the wizard will generate some example exported function for you. Follow the examples to create your own export functions.